# Not able to create hyperlink when using jquery replace function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

I am trying to look for a text(sentence) on a page and then replace that with a new text. The below code works fine if the text to be replaced is just text. However i also want to include a hyperlink in the new text.

**Original Text**: It seems you have already entered this survey.
**New text**: It seems that someone has XYZ, to go back to your PP account please use this URL: www.xyz.com

Below is the code sample i am using

```
$ ("*").contents().each(function() {
if(this.nodeType == 3)
    this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace("Old text", "Please click this link");
});
```

If i try to add hyperlink tag to the text above ""Please click this link", it does not create a hyperlink, instead displays it as a text with the html tag visible

Comment: Sorry i am new to this. Do u mean the source code?

Comment: that is the native javascript `String` `replace` function - nothing at all to do with jQuery

Comment: simple issue: you can't add HTML to a text node nodeValue and expect HTML - you just get the text as you've seen

Answer (score 0):

> However i also want to include a hyperlink in the new text.

First clear the existing nodeValue

```
this.nodeValue = "";
```

Now create a new *anchor* element

```
var aNode = document.createElement("a");
aNode.setAttribute( "href", "#" );
aNode.innerText =  "Please click this link";
```

Now insert `aNode` this before the nextSibling of the `this` node

```
var nextNode = this.nextSibling;
var parentNode = this.parentNode;
parentNode.insertBefore( aNode, nextNode );
```

**DEMO**

```js
$("*").contents().each(function() {
  if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf("Old text") > -1) {
    this.nodeValue = "";

    var aNode = document.createElement("a");
    aNode.setAttribute("href", "#");
    aNode.innerText = "Please click this link";

    var nextNode = this.nextSibling;
    var parentNode = this.parentNode;
    parentNode.insertBefore(aNode, nextNode);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parentDiv">
  <div>prev text</div>
  Old text
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, however what if i just want the word "link" to be a hyperlink and not the entire sentence